# Data Changes between Axios Post Implementation

Tags: axios, next.js

pages/login

```
const data = ({
            email: email,
            password: password
        })

        console.log(data)

        
        const {details} = await axios.post('/api/users/login', data, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
        })
```

pages/api/login

```
const handler = nc();

console.log('beginning login api')

handler.post(async(req, res) => {
    await database.connect();
    console.log('db connected')
    console.log(req)
```

My issue is that the console.log data in the login is logging out correctly but the req being printed out in the api is logging a long list which I will provide a snippet of

```
<ref *2> IncomingMessage {
_readableState: ReadableState {
objectMode: false,
highWaterMark: 16384,
buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
length: 0,
pipes: [],
flowing: true,
ended: true,
endEmitted: true,
reading: false,
constructed: true,
sync: true,
needReadable: false,
emittedReadable: false,
readableListening: false,
resumeScheduled: false,
errorEmitted: false,
```

[console.log(data) output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEMz8.png)

UPDATE----

```
const user = await user.findOne({ email: req.body.email});

res.send ({
            token,
            email: user.email,
            name: user.name,
            _id: user._id,
            createdAt: user.createdAt
        })
```

this returns the server response list I refer to. I tried req.body. for each instead of the user. as well but got the same response.

UPDATE 2

So the axios request and response on the API side are both correct.

when I console.log(details) which is assigned to the axios request it returns undefined.

Comment: The console output you posted for `pages/api/login` shows `ServerResponse` which means you're actually printing the `Response`, not the `Request`. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: Sorry yes you were correct I had printed the response further down and copied it by mistake, updated with the start of the request console log output

Comment: When you say `pages/login` logs correctly, what does that printed output look like? Are you trying to get `pages/login` and `pages/api/login` to both print the same exact thing?

Comment: I have edited the original to add a post of the console output in pages/login. I then want these parameters to be passed to the login api through an axios.post request, but instead of receiving those parameters the request returns the large list of objects previously mentioned

Answer (score 0):

That "long list" you're seeing from `pages/api/login` is the `IncomingMessage` object. If you're looking for just the data, you want to `console.log(req.body)`.

Comment: req.body returns the same thing, even req.body.email returns the same incoming message object, I am unsure why this is

Comment: Sorry no my mistake you are correct, req.body returns the correct response. The issue now is the response, the serverResponse that I had intially added to the original post is still outputting the same, I shall add code to the original

Comment: console logging res.body returns undefined

Comment: @sr864 I'm not even sure what's going on anymore, but try `console.log(res.req.body)`.

Comment: sorry I'm quite to new to nextjs so I do appreciate the help! That logged the correct response, I am using js-cookies in my project and there is a userInfo = state() object that is returning undefined everytime I try to login but all the responses we have checked are correct so not too sure what to do next, but thank you!

Comment: @sr864 No worries! Just keep at it.

Answer (score 0):

for the axios.post const, it has to be named data not details or any other name, there is a strict 5/6 names that can be destructue